# How to zero-pad filenames of numbered, delimitered alphnumeric strings of arbitrary length in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm seeking an elegant CLI way to zero-pad filenames that are numbered alpha-numeric strings of an arbitrary length, and which have dashes in place of spaces.

E.g. I would like the following list of files:

```
1-file-name-of-one-length.mp3
2-shorter-file-name.mp3
3-really-really-really-long-file-name.mp3
> ..
10-another-file-name.mp3
```

To become:

```
01-file-name-of-one-length.mp3
02-shorter-file-name.mp3
03-really-really-really-long-file-name.mp3
> ..
10-another-file-name.mp3
```

I've spent a day learning about awk, bash and rename approaches to zero-padding, but previous questions here and tutorials I've found seem to assume either a purely numerical or a standardised-length file-naming scheme. In such cases the fields between the '-' delimiters can be broken down and re-assembled in a predictable ways with e.g. awk. My strings are of unknown length, so contain an unknown number of fields between the '-' characters.

I'm envisioning the answer will be a 'for loop'. The logic of what I want the loop to do is something like:
Read file name to the first '-' character.
Determine if the number preceding the first '-' is a single or double-digit number.
If it is a single digit number, insert a '0' character in front of it.

**EDIT FOR ANSWER**

Renaud pointed out the correct syntax for a simple for-loop (my own attempt along these lines had resulted in padding of double-digit numbers too, but Renaud's code worked)

for f in [0-9]-*.mp3; do mv "$f" "0$f"; done

Comment: Do the numbers always appear at the beginning? How wide should the padded numbers be? Just 2 characters?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In this specific case only two digits, but a solution that can accommodate an arbitrary number could be helpful for myself and others. And the numberes do always begin at the start of the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pad with one 0 only:

```
for f in [0-9]-*.mp3; do mv "$f" "0$f"; done
```

In case there could be no files matching the `[0-9]-*.mp3` pattern it is probably better to also use the `nullglob` option (in a subshell just to automatically restore the `nullglob` status afterwards):

```
( shopt -s nullglob; for f in [0-9]-*.mp3; do mv "$f" "0$f"; done )
```

If you want the leading number on `n` digits instead of just 2, say 3:

```
(
n=3
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for f in +([0-9])-*.mp3; do
  printf -v g '%0*d-%s' "$n" "${f%%-*}" "${f#*-}"
  mv "$f" "$g"
done
)
```

Finally, if you do not know the value of `n`, want to automatically compute it, and assuming it must be the maximum number of leading digits in these file names:

```
(
shopt -s extglob nullglob
n=0
for f in +([0-9])-*.mp3; do
  g="${f%%-*}"
  (( n = "${#g}" > n ? "${#g}" : n ))
done
for f in +([0-9])-*.mp3; do
  printf -v g '%0*d-%s' "$n" "${f%%-*}" "${f#*-}"
  mv "$f" "$g"
done
)
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud. I attempted this earlier but my syntax must have been incorrect because all numbers (even double digits) were zero-padded. Copy/pasting your code has worked. Thanks for helping my learning. I'll accept the answer as soon as the site will let me.

Comment: You're welcome. See my last update for more than 2 digits.